# How to display the latest tweet in a single line?

Tags: twitter

How do I display my latest tweet in a single line instead of a 'li'?

Right now I'm using this code:

```
<div id="twitter_update_list"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=[twittername]&include_rts=true&count=1&callback=twitterCallback2"></script>
```

Which outputs:

```
<div id="twitter_update_list">
  <li>latest tweet</li>
</div>
```

I want the output to be:

```
<div id="twitter_update_list">
  Latest tweet
</div>
```

Comment: save the output somewhere and then trim it as per your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is what I've did. I added an extra html line:

```
<span id="latest-weet"></span>
```

With a litle bit of jquery:

```
$('#latest-tweet').html($('#twitter_update_list li span').html());
```

Let's not forget the css:

```
#twitter_update_list {
    display: none;
}
```

I admit it's not the best solution but it works.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hb86K/